# Selenium driver maximize() exact behavior OR how to predict when browser will have focus

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

What are the exact possible implications of using `Driver.manage().window().maximize()` under different circumstances? Does it only Maximize the browser window or it also brings it to foreground? Switches the focus onto the browser?

After running the command on a node through Selenium grid, the browser window is sometimes in focus and sometimes NOT! And I don't seem to understand the pattern and what it is dependant on?

This is important to me because I'm executing some `Java AWT Robot` actions right after running the browser that is supposed to run against the browser window and this fails when the browser is not in focus!

I guess my question is: How can I predict when the opened browser will be in focus and ready for sending Robot key commands? Is it dependant on OS or Selenium? If Selenium, how to manipulate it and if OS, how to eliminate the possibility of the opened browser not having focus?